# Reverse array index of ints

Tags: java, arrays

I am attempting to reverse an Array of int values. It does not seem to be doing it correctly.
You will note that I am printing in different ways, like `Array.toString()` and also using `println`.

The original array prints:

```
1 4 9 16 9
```

I need it to print:

```
9 16 9 4 1
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ReverseArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] data = { 1, 4, 9, 16, 9 };
        reverseArray(data);
        int[] dataR = reverseArray(data);
        System.out.println("Reveresed data " + Arrays.toString(dataR));
    }

    public static int[] reverseArray(int[] data) { // returns the reverse of the
                                                    // array data
        // int [] data = new int[5];
        int[] reversedData = new int[data.length];

        data[0] = 1;
        data[1] = 4;
        data[2] = 9;
        data[3] = 16;
        data[4] = 9;

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println("Original Array: " + data[i]);
        }

        int reveresedData[] = data;

        for (int i = 0; i < reveresedData.length - 1; i++) {
            reversedData[(data.length - 1) - i] = data[i];
            System.out.println(reveresedData[i]);
        }
        return reveresedData;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you having so much of duplicate code, and re-assignment of same thing again and again?

Comment: Most part of your code seem unnecessary..

Comment: Its a class session. Going through loops, arrays, different ways to print arrays and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Using For each loop : Smarter way)
Create a method as follows:

```
 private int[] reverseArray(int [] array1){
        int index=array1.length;
        int [] array2 = new int[index];
        for(int i:array1){
            array2[index-1]= i;
            index--;
        }
        return array2;    
}
```

And call it like:

```
int [] array1 = {1,2,3};
int reversedArray[] = reverseArray(array1);
```

Thats it.

Comment: how is a `for each` a smarter way than a regular for loop?

Comment: native vs normal code difference. what we do in regular for loop, is little slow than for each loop. you can check using a big array traversal.
because native is always faster than applicatin level code.

Comment: I seem to be getting an out of bounds exception?

    array2[index]= i;

Comment: I have Edited Answer. There was a small counter mistake. now test it, It should be running now as a charm. i dint runt it, i have only written the logic here so Also please let me know after running, if it helps you.

Comment: Yep, works. Thanks. Question though, what is the syntax
     for(int i:array1)
Is this just short for
    for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)?

Comment: it is called "for each loop", and not the short form, it is new loop introduced i java 6, but does the same work as for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) but reduces human efforts. just search on google about java for each loop. it's syntex is like- for(ContentTypeOfArray x : ArrayName){Here for each iteration you will get content in x}. I always prefer to use for each loop over normal for loop because it minimizes human errors of maintaining start index, loop limit, increment etc.

Comment: For that algorithm to work, did you write it out first, or has this come with great experience?
I only ask this as I am just starting out with regards to programming.

Comment: @PrimalScientist: no i dint write it before, and you are right about exp. it will come to you also as you get exp.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the following:

```
int reveresedData[] = data;
```

makes `reveresedData` point to the same array as `data`. Instead, you need to create a new array (or change the algorithm so that it reverses the array in place).

To create a new array, you could use either of:

```
int reveresedData[] = new int[data.length];
int reveresedData[] = data.clone();
```

Comment: i would have recommended Arrays.copyOf(...)

Answer (score 1):

should be something like this:

```
int reversed[] = new int[data.length];
```

This will allocate space for a new array that you can fill with the values of data in reverse order.

```
for (int i = 0,j=reversed.length-1; i < reversed.length-1; i++;j--){
        reversed[i]=data[j];
    }
```

Comment: My syntax may be off in the for loop, as i didnt type this out in a web ide.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic approach to reverse array of any size. It reverses the original array.

```
public class ReverseMyArray {
public static int[] reverseArray(int[] array) {
    for(int i=0; i<array.length/2; i++) {
        int temp = array[i];                    // temp is a temporary variable of type int
        array[i] = array[array.length-1-i];
        array[array.length-1-i] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {1,4,9,16,9};
    int[] newArray = reverseArray(array);
    for(int i=0; i<newArray.length; i++) {          
        System.out.print(newArray[i]+" ");      // Print the reversed array values
    }
}
}
```